# Binary range identification in terms of subset

Tags: sets, binary, pattern-recognition

Given a range of "K" bit numbers, we want to identify the whole range by using a subset within that range, with the following criteria -

1. If there are > "n" consecutive 0s, it becomes the 1st [00] prefix identifier value - **case (a)**
2. If there are <= "p" consecutive 0s, (where p < n),  that value has to be identified as the 2nd/3rd/4th [01/10/11].. prefix identifier value, upto a limit of "r", such that it would accommodate all the values of case (b) in terms of case (a) above - **case (b)**
3. If there are values where consecutive 0s are > "p" AND <= "n", then they will be identified as themselves, without any prefix - **case (c)**

How to identify all these values dynamically, without saving all those results or iterating all those values. This will be efficient for larger "K" bit range.

Appreciate if you can give some pointers on how to achieve this.

Many thanks.

Example:

```
K = 8 bits
n = 3 -> minimum 4 consecutive 0s for case (a)
p = 2 -> maximum 2 consecutive 0s for case (b)
r = 4 -> maximum limit of 4 prefix identifier [00/01/10/11] for case (a) and case (b) combined
```

Identification:

```
00000000 - [00] 00000000        (a) 
00000001 - [00] 00000001        (a) 
00000010 - [00] 00000010        (a) 
00000011 - [00] 00000011        (a) 
00000100 - [00] 00000100        (a) 
00000101 - [00] 00000101        (a) 
00000110 - [00] 00000110        (a) 
00000111 - [00] 00000111        (a) 
00001000 - [00] 00001000        (a) 
00001001 - [00] 00001001        (a) 
00001010 - [00] 00001010        (a) 
00001011 - [00] 00001011        (a) 
00001100 - [00] 00001100        (a) 
00001101 - [00] 00001101        (a) 
00001110 - [00] 00001110        (a) 
00001111 - [00] 00001111        (a) 


00010000 - [00] 00010000        (a) 
00010001 - 00010001                 (c)         
00010010 - 00010010                 (c)
00010011 - 00010011                 (c)
00010100 - 00010100                 (c)
00010101 - 00010101                 (c)
00010110 - 00010110                 (c)
00010111 - 00010111                 (c)
00011000 - 00011000                 (c)
00011001 - 00011001                 (c)
00011010 - 00011010                 (c)
00011011 - 00011011                 (c)
00011100 - 00011100                 (c)
00011101 - 00011101                 (c)
00011110 - 00011110                 (c)
00011111 - 00011111                 (c)


00100000 - [00] 00100000        (a) 
00100001 - [00] 00100001        (a) 
00100010 - 00100010                 (c)
00100011 - 00100011                 (c)
00100100 - [01] 00000000                (b)
00100101 - [10] 00000000                (b)
00100110 - [11] 00000000                (b)
00100111 - [01] 00000001                (b)
00101000 - 00101000                 (c)
00101001 - [10] 00000001                (b)
00101010 - [11] 00000001                (b)
00101011 - [01] 00000010                (b)
00101100 - [10] 00000010                (b)
00101101 - [11] 00000010                (b)
00101110 - [01] 00000011                (b)
00101111 - [10] 00000011                (b)


00110000 - [00] 00110000        (a) 
00110001 - 00110001                 (c)
00110010 - [11] 00000011                (b)
00110011 - [01] 00000100                (b)
00110100 - [10] 00000100                (b)
00110101 - [11] 00000100                (b)
00110110 - [01] 00000101                (b)
00110111 - [10] 00000101                (b)
00111000 - 00111000                 (c)
00111001 - [11] 00000101                (b)
00111010 - [01] 00000110                (b)
00111011 - [10] 00000110                (b)
00111100 - [11] 00000110                (b)
00111101 - [01] 00000111                (b)
00111110 - [10] 00000111                (b)
00111111 - [11] 00000111                (b)


01000000 - [00] 01000000        (a) 
01000001 - [00] 01000001        (a) 
01000010 - [00] 01000010        (a) 
01000011 - [00] 01000011        (a) 
01000100 - 01000100                 (c)
01000101 - 01000101                 (c)
01000110 - 01000110                 (c)
01000111 - 01000111                 (c)
01001000 - 01001000                 (c)
01001001 - [01] 00001000                (b)
01001010 - [10] 00001000                (b)
01001011 - [11] 00001000                (b)
01001100 - [01] 00001001                (b)
01001101 - [10] 00001001                (b)
01001110 - [11] 00001001                (b)
01001111 - [01] 00001010                (b)


01010000 - [00] 01010000        (a) 
01010001 - 01010001                 (c)
01010010 - [10] 00001010                (b)
01010011 - [11] 00001010                (b)
01010100 - [01] 00001011                (b)
01010101 - [10] 00001011                (b)
01010110 - [11] 00001011                (b)
01010111 - [01] 00001100                (b)
01011000 - 01011000                 (c)
01011001 - [10] 00001100                (b)
01011010 - [11] 00001100                (b)
01011011 - [01] 00001101                (b)
01011100 - [10] 00001101                (b)
01011101 - [11] 00001101                (b)
01011110 - [01] 00001110                (b)
01011111 - [10] 00001110                (b)


01100000 - [00] 01100000        (a) 
01100001 - [00] 01100001        (a) 
01100010 - 01100010                 (c)
01100011 - 01100011                 (c)
01100100 - [11] 00001110                (b)
01100101 - [01] 00001111                (b)
01100110 - [10] 00001111                (b)
01100111 - [11] 00001111                (b)
01101000 - 01101000                 (c)
01101001 - [01] 00010000                (b)
01101010 - [10] 00010000                (b)
01101011 - [11] 00010000                (b)
01101100 - [01] 00100000                (b)
01101101 - [10] 00100000                (b)
01101110 - [11] 00100000                (b)
01101111 - [01] 00100001                (b)


01110000 - [10] 00100001                (b)
01110001 - 01110001                 (c)
01110010 - [11] 00100001                (b)
01110011 - [01] 00110000                (b)
01110100 - [10] 00110000                (b)
01110101 - [11] 00110000                (b)
01110110 - [01] 01000000                (b)
01110111 - [10] 01000000                (b)
01111000 - 01111000                 (c)
01111001 - [11] 01000000                (b)
01111010 - [01] 01000001                (b)
01111011 - [10] 01000001                (b)
01111100 - [11] 01000001                (b)
01111101 - [01] 01000010                (b)
01111110 - [10] 01000010                (b)
01111111 - [11] 01000010                (b)


10000000 - [00] 10000000        (a) 
10000001 - [00] 10000001        (a) 
10000010 - [00] 10000010        (a) 
10000011 - [00] 10000011        (a) 
10000100 - [00] 10000100        (a) 
10000101 - [00] 10000101        (a) 
10000110 - [00] 10000110        (a) 
10000111 - [00] 10000111        (a) 
10001000 - 10001000                 (c)
10001001 - 10001001                 (c)
10001010 - 10001010                 (c)
10001011 - 10001011                 (c)
10001100 - 10001100                 (c)
10001101 - 10001101                 (c)
10001110 - 10001110                 (c)
10001111 - 10001111                 (c)


10010000 - [00] 10010000        (a) 
10010001 - 10010001                 (c)
10010010 - [01] 01000011                (b)
10010011 - [10] 01000011                (b)
10010100 - [11] 01000011                (b)
10010101 - [01] 01010000                (b)
10010110 - [10] 01010000                (b)
10010111 - [11] 01010000                (b)
10011000 - 10011000                 (c)
10011001 - [01] 01100000                (b)
10011010 - [10] 01100000                (b)
10011011 - [11] 01100000                (b)
10011100 - [01] 01100001                (b)
10011101 - [10] 01100001                (b)
10011110 - [11] 01100001                (b)
10011111 - [01] 10000000                (b)


10100000 - [00] 10100000        (a) 
10100001 - [00] 10100001        (a) 
10100010 - 10100010                 (c)
10100011 - 10100011                 (c)
10100100 - [10] 10000000                (b)
10100101 - [11] 10000000                (b)
10100110 - [01] 10000001                (b)
10100111 - [10] 10000001                (b)
10101000 - 10101000                 (c)
10101001 - [11] 10000001                (b)
10101010 - [01] 10000010                (b)
10101011 - [10] 10000010                (b)
10101100 - [11] 10000010                (b)
10101101 - [01] 10000011                (b)
10101110 - [10] 10000011                (b)
10101111 - [11] 10000011                (b)


10110000 - [00] 10110000        (a) 
10110001 - 10110001                 (c)
10110010 - [01] 10000100                (b)
10110011 - [10] 10000100                (b)
10110100 - [11] 10000100                (b)
10110101 - [01] 10000101                (b)
10110110 - [10] 10000101                (b)
10110111 - [11] 10000101                (b)
10111000 - 10111000                 (c)
10111001 - [01] 10000110                (b)
10111010 - [10] 10000110                (b)
10111011 - [11] 10000110                (b)
10111100 - [01] 10000111                (b)
10111101 - [10] 10000111                (b)
10111110 - [11] 10000111                (b)
10111111 - [01] 10010000                (b)


11000000 - [00] 11000000        (a) 
11000001 - [00] 11000001        (a) 
11000010 - [00] 11000010        (a) 
11000011 - [00] 11000011        (a) 
11000100 - 11000100                 (c)
11000101 - 11000101                 (c)
11000110 - 11000110                 (c)
11000111 - 11000111                 (c)
11001000 - 11001000                 (c)
11001001 - [10] 10010000                (b)
11001010 - [11] 10010000                (b)
11001011 - [01] 10100000                (b)
11001100 - [10] 10100000                (b)
11001101 - [11] 10100000                (b)
11001110 - [01] 10100001                (b)
11001111 - [10] 10100001                (b)


11010000 - [00] 11010000        (a) 
11010001 - 11010001                 (c)
11010010 - [11] 10100001                (b)
11010011 - [01] 10110000                (b)
11010100 - [10] 10110000                (b)
11010101 - [11] 10110000                (b)
11010110 - [01] 11000000                (b)
11010111 - [10] 11000000                (b)
11011000 - [11] 11000000                (b)
11011001 - [01] 11000001                (b)
11011010 - [10] 11000001                (b)
11011011 - [11] 11000001                (b)
11011100 - [01] 11000010                (b)
11011101 - [10] 11000010                (b)
11011110 - [11] 11000010                (b)
11011111 - [01] 11000011                (b)


11100000 - [00] 11100000        (a) 
11100001 - [00] 11100001        (a) 
11100010 - 11100010                 (c)
11100011 - 11100011                 (c)
11100100 - [10] 11000011                (b)
11100101 - [11] 11000011                (b)
11100110 - [01] 11010000                (b)
11100111 - [10] 11010000                (b)
11101000 - 11101000                 (c)
11101001 - [11] 11010000                (b)
11101010 - [01] 11100000                (b)
11101011 - [10] 11100000                (b)
11101100 - [11] 11100000                (b)
11101101 - [01] 11100001                (b)
11101110 - [10] 11100001                (b)
11101111 - [11] 11100001                (b)


11110000 - [00] 11110000        (a) 
11110001 - 11110001                 (c)
11110010 - [0100] 11110000              (b)
11110011 - [0101] 11110000              (b)
11110100 - [0110] 11110000              (b)
11110101 - [0111] 11110000              (b)
11110110 - [1000] 11110000              (b)
11110111 - [1001] 11110000              (b)
11111000 - 11111000                 (c)
11111001 - [1010] 11110000              (b)
11111010 - [1011] 11110000              (b)
11111011 - [1100] 11110000              (b)
11111100 - [1101] 11110000              (b)
11111101 - [1110] 11110000              (b)
11111110 - [11110] 11110000             (b)
11111111 - [11111] 11110000             (b)
```